# Specify (git) Source Branch for TFS (VSO) builds

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

We have a VSO Git repository, TFS build definition and a script to kick off builds at specific commits.
The problem (annoyance) is when looking at the list of completed builds in VSO the "Source Branch" column always shows "(no branch)" (however "Source Version" does show the expected commit ID).

The build definition is just a vanilla `GitTemplate.12.xaml` that has the `CheckoutOverride` parameter, here's how the builds get queued:

```
$tfs = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($TfsProjectCollectionUrl, $TfsServiceAccount)
$buildServer = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$buildDefinition = $buildServer.GetBuildDefinition($TeamProjectName, $BuildDefinitionName)
$buildRequest = $buildDefinition.CreateBuildRequest()
$processParameters = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::DeserializeProcessParameters($buildRequest.BuildDefinition.ProcessParameters)

$processParameters.CheckoutOverride = $GitCommitHash;

$buildRequest.ProcessParameters = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::SerializeProcessParameters($processParameters)

$queued = $buildServer.QueueBuild($buildRequest)
```

1. Is there a way to specify the branch + commit, without using tags(*).
2. What if the commit hash is found in multiple branches? (e.g. `git cherry-pick`)

(*) Many of these are buddy builds in working branches and creating ad-hoc tags would pollute that namespace or require garbage collection.

(**) Can't use `refs/heads/...` - builds have to correlate to specific commits, not HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

The "Source Branch" column is supposed to show the name of "Default branch for Manual builds" in Build Definition. For example, if you select a default branch for manual builds in Build Definition, you'll see the corresponding "Source Branch" in completed builds, but if you let the default branch for manual build blank, the "Source Branch" will show (no branch), see the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

So, you need to specify the Default branch for Manual builds, then you'll get the correct Source Branch.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. I checked my own build _definition_ and default branch is already `refs/heads/master` but new build _requests_ still show `(no branch)` when `CheckoutOverride` is specified in the request.

Comment: You are correct that if specify the value in CheckoutOverride, the Source Branch will show (no branch). In my opinion, Checkout Override can override the default branch and commit, you can specify the value of Checkout Override with both from master and branch, so the Source Branch can't tell it's source branch. You may try to create two build defination, one for master, another for branch, if the checkout override commit belongs to master/branch, then use master/branch build defination.

Comment: Yeah as I noted in the question the commit can be in >1 branch, although in the majority of cases it will be unambiguous. For example when the commit only exists in a single branch (e.g. a working branch before it's merged to master) then specifying such a commit in `CheckoutOverride` will imply a branch as well.